# How can i add onClick() events to an <i></i> icon format?

Tags: html, triggers, onclick, icons

I tried alot of things but they don't seem to work.
Heres my code that I want to trigger:

```
...
<body>
  ...
   <div class="navbar">
       ...
        <div class="searchIcon">
            <i class="fi-br-search"></i> //I want this (icon/line) to trigger testSearch()
        </div>
       ...
   </div>
  ...
<body>
```

And here's the js i wrote:

```
function testSearch() {
    alert("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `onclick` attribute:

```js
function testSearch() {
    alert("Hello")
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="navbar">
        <div class="searchIcon">
            <i onclick="testSearch()" class="fi-br-search">asdasd</i> 
        </div>
   </div>
<body>
```

It's better to nest the icon in a button and give the click handler to the button.

Answer (score 1):

the first solution is to simply use `onclick`, but `onclick` is not recommended, use `eventListeners` instead

```js
function testSearch() {
    alert("Hello")
}
document.getElementById("i").addEventListener("click", testSearch)
```

```html
   <div class="navbar">
        <div class="searchIcon">
            <i id="i" class="fi-br-search">click me</i> 
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This doesnt look like it gives an alert, i have spam clicked it so much but it does nothing.....

Comment: @Endor it works perfectly for me, try running the code snippet again and click on the text